# htaccess not allowed to load local resource error

Tags: php, .htaccess

The css *materialdesignicons.min.css* and *typicons.css* are linked in header.php

```
root
 |--vendors
    |--mdi
       |--css
          |--materialdesignicons.min.css
 |--view
    |--header.php
```

**header.php**

```
*** The header.php original code 
< link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" >

*** The header.php with dirname(__DIR__) 
 < link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo dirname(__DIR__) ?>/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
```

When accessing the site with using .htaccess rewrite rule I'm getting an error.

```
    Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp_v7_3_27/htdocs/mywebsite/vendors/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css
```

However this is a valid path.

Comment: You are confusing file system paths, with URLs.

Comment: Got it and it should not mixed up. How do I load the file correctly?

Comment: If you just use a path starting with a `/`, that is always relative to the web root. If you want to keep your project flexible, in that you could also put it into some sub-folder below the web root, then I would use a constant for the path prefix.